# How to solve unknown sender to specific name in WR-contact-form?

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, contact-form, auto-responder

I installed wordpress plugin [WR-contact-form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wr-contactform/) but in auto responder I get following things in mail.

Snapshots:

http://puu.sh/kUxUm/8b0012bf52.png/

http://puu.sh/kUxWh/c7082993a4.png

http://puu.sh/kUypk/9eca6d9b68.png

How can I change unknown sender to my name in the mail.

Also how can I add more fields like signed-by, mailed-by in the mail?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use contact form 7 plugin. It's better.

Answer (score 1):

Enter Wordpress Admin Panel-> WR ContacForm->Settings -> From Email Option

Comment: As dingo_d said, use contact form 7. It is really better. I am afraid there are no options in this WR-ContactForm plugin such options as additional fields. And if they are they are too limited. You have to manually extend the functionality of this plugin if you want to use it

Comment: how to extend functionality?

Comment: Look at this article http://wptavern.com/how-to-extend-a-wordpress-plugin-without-losing-your-changes